# Laravel 7 vanilla JavaScript call API

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios, laravel-7

I created an API in JavaScript with Axios to get details using the POST method. It works well with .html, but it does not work when I include it in my Laravel 7 development. There's no error in the console.

I tried connecting the API by including PHP class too. I don't understand why it does not work.

**Form**

```
<form>
<div class="pull-left">
    <input type="text" class="typeahead" id="place" placeholder="Enter Place..">
</div>
<div class="pull-left dst">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="dst" id="dst">DST</label>
</div>
<input type="text" id="latitude" placeholder="latitude" readonly>
<input type="text" id="longitude" placeholder="longitude" readonly>
<input type="text" id="timezone" placeholder="timezone" readonly>
</form>
```

**Javascript API code**

```js
let apiKey = "";
let userId = "";
var getGeoDetails = function (a) {
var b = [],
d = "http://localhost/geodetails/",
e = function (a, c) {
  var data = {
    place: a,
    maxRows: 6,
  };
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://api.vedicrishiastro.com/v1/geo_details",
    headers: {
      authorization: "Basic " + btoa(userId + ":" + apiKey),
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      b = [];
      var d = response.data.geonames;
      console.log(d);
      $.each(d, function (a, c) {
        var d = c.place_name + " " + c.country_code;
        b.push({
          value: d,
          latitude: c.latitude,
          longitude: c.longitude,
          countryCode: c.country_code,
          timeZoneId: c.timezone_id,
        });
      }),
        c(b);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
$(a).typeahead(
{ minLength: 3 },
{
  source: function (a, b) {
    e(a, b);
  },
}
),
$(a).on("typeahead:selected", function (a, b) {
  var c = b.timeZoneId,
    e = $('input[name="dst"]:checked').length > 0;
  $("#latitude").val(b.latitude), $("#longitude").val(b.longitude);
  console.log(c);
  console.log(e);
  var data = {
    country_code: c,
    isDst: e,
  };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  fetch("http://api.vedicrishiastro.com/v1/timezone", {
    method: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      authorization: "Basic " + btoa(userId + ":" + apiKey),
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      $("#timezone").val(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
};
getGeoDetails(".typeahead");
```

Comment: Show code that would help :)

Comment: added the code.

Comment: The code is provided by the API service provider. I just made a few changes. Previously it was using php class which I included in my laravel. Since that did not work I made changes in js to remove php class to call the API.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to debug the problem? Like: is the request sent properly? Does Laravel receive the request properly?

Comment: Laravel is not able to send POST request.